# Calculus Question (Maclaurin's theorem)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It's given that $y=\frac{1}{1+\sin (2x)}$, show that when $x=0$, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=8$ Using Maclaurin's theorem, find the first three terms for $y$.  Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{y}{x^2+x}$.

My attempt,

$$y=\frac{1}{1+\sin 2x}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2\cos (2x)}{(1+\sin (2x))^2}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{4(\sin ^2(2x)+\sin (2x)+2\cos ^2(2x))}{(\sin (2x)+1)^3}$$

When $x=0$, $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{4(\sin ^2(0)+\sin (0)+2\cos ^2(0))}{(\sin (0)+1)^3}$$

$$=8(shown)$$

Then how do I proceed to first three terms for $y$ by using Maclaurin's theorem and how do I evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{y}{x^2+x}$.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maclaurin series for $y(x)$ is:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{y^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
where $y^{(n)}$ is the $n$'th derivative. Therefore, the first three terms are:
$$y(x)=y(0)+y'(0)x+\dfrac{y''(0)}{2!}x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^3)$$
With $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=-2$ and $y''(0)=8$, this yields:
$$y(x)=1-2x+4x^2$$
You can then compute the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{y}{x^2+x}$ as:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{y}{x^2+x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{4x^2-2x+1}{x^2+x}=4$$

Comment: The limit at $x\to +\infty$ has nothing to do with the MacLaurin series centered at $x=0$.